# WPF InputGesture hides character from TextInput handler even when Command is disabled

Tags: wpf, command, textinput

I have this:

```
public static RoutedUICommand SplitLine = 
    new RoutedUICommand("Split Line", "SplitLine", typeof(TabItem), 
        new InputGestureCollection(
           new InputGesture[] { new KeyGesture(Key.OemPeriod) }));
```

Which allows me to run the SplitLine command by hitting an OemPeriod. Works great so far.

Next I have this, which correctly disables SplitLine under certain conditions:

```
static void splitline_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = FalseForSomeReason();
}
```

The problem is I also have this code, which is functional when SplitLine can't execute:

```
void myControl_TextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e) {
    // this code never gets an OemPeriod;
}
```

The problem is that TextInput handler never sees the OemPeriod. Other chars come through no problem. I've also tried TextInput, PreviewTextInput, Keydown - the OemPeriod doesn't come through any of these.

Is there a way to see the OemPeriod in my control via TextInput (or something) when the SplitLine command is disabled?

Comment: My workaround(?) is to remove the keybinding when SplitLine is not executable, and add it back when SplitLine is available again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is to set the ContinueRouting flag in the CanExecute method when CanExecute is false:

```
static void splitline_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e) {
    e.CanExecute = FalseForSomeReason();
    if (e.CanExecute == false) e.ContinueRouting = true;   // <=== Add this!
}
```

This allows the OemPeriod to continue looking for something to handle it (in this case the TextInput handler). Without this, all processing of OemPeriod stops when CanExecute gives the thumbs down.